# <ol><li> positions odd when image is aligned to the left

Tags: css, image, html-lists, alignment

http://www.brixwork.com/realtors/blog/marketing-promotion/combining-pdfs-online-for-a-comprehensive-presentation/

I have two occurrences of `<ol><li>`s in this blog post. The first instance is formatted fine, using this CSS:

```
.post_content ul, .post_content ol {
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

And then, below, beside the PDF icon image (which is floated left), the bullets pull to the left side and don't quite line up properly.. what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try adding

`list-style-position: inside;` to your css for the `<ol>`.

Basically, your `20px` of padding is going up against the left border of the containing element and getting eaten by the floated picture. Moving the list numbers "inside" the containing element lets them behave like the `<p>` text around them.

This will also indent the `<ol>` that you have that is not affected by the float, so you may want to make a special class for this `<ol>` (or get rid of the left padding, if you only added it to make the first `<ol>` line up).

Comment: `list-style-position: outside;` is the *default*

Answer (score 0):

*Cameron is right (+1).  That is the best solution.*

However, some people have solved this problem simply by:

1. Hiding the numbers/bullets (i.e. `list-style:none;`)
2. Hard-coding the bullets/numbers yourself

Example:

```
<ol style="list-style:none;">
  <li>1. Create PDF forms that can collect data</li>
  <li>2. Include multimedia (pictures, videos) from multiple sources into the PDF</li>
  <li>3. Sign PDFs</li>
  <li>4. And more!</li>
</ol>
```

*Personally wouldn't do it the hard-coded way, but it can be a useful tool in your belt.*

Here is a great article about how to style the *numbers* of ordered lists with CSS without hard-coding the numbers as I outlined above:

- [Styling ordered list numbers](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201105/styling_ordered_list_numbers/)